# Is there a way to avoid cache in Laravel projects during development?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm not a front-end specialist, so I find myself trying classes, styles, combinations. So make a change, refresh the page, try another, refresh the page. Then other ordinary cases, I add a typo, fix the error, and refresh the page.

Every time I do this, something is cached, and I don't seem to find any way of skipping this, so I have to wait for a while until I can see my changes. How can I disable this?

Running the following is not working, nor a hard reload.

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

I found that adding this on my .env file should do the trick. But it is not working either. Is there any other way? Also, what is the downside of doing this while developing locally?

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
CACHE_EXPIRE=-1
```

Comment: Are you running `php artisan view:cache` as part of your deployment script? If so, don't run it.

Comment: this sounds like it could just be browser caching ... the browser will cache assets like javascript and css and the page itself, you probably need to do a hard refresh (hold shift + click reload) ... should make it download everything required for the page again

Comment: That doesn't work. It is not browser unfortunatelly. As for my deployment script @IGP, I'm not sure, I'm just running npm run development, which runs mix. Probably something in there. Thanks

Comment: Are you running `npx mix watch`?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "*something is cached*" - what, exactly?  If you mean CSS/JS, then look at your webpack etc, and [use versioning](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/versioning).  If you work with your browser's devtools open, you'll get the option to disable cache (and it will also show you exactly what is being read from cache). If you mean views, maybe you're using `view:cache`, or other `artisan` cache commands, as already suggested?  You should not use any of the `cache` options in development, and if you have, use the corresponding `clear` option to remove.

Comment: If you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in the `.env` file you should be good to go. Any view file change is picked up automatically. No need to clear the view caches. Make sure you don't cache the config neither. That's a tricky one when developing a new project and some config change doesn't seem to pick up. Another trick is to push the `shift` button and click browser reload. It forces to reload all files from scratch, including javascript. happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use [versioning](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/versioning) in Laravel Mix. To assist with long-term caching, Laravel Mix provides the `mix.version()` method to enable file hashing, such as `app.js?id=8e5c48eadbfdd5458ec6`. This is useful for cache-busting purposes.

For example, see the following in webpack.mix.js.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ])
    .version();
```